# force dragend when collision is detected in kineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

How do I make the dragged shape stop being dragged (`dragend` action) when intersects with the borders of another shape? I already tested the collision detection. What I want for now is how to actually **stop** it from moving, and force the drop.

IMPORTANT EDIT: I need to manipulate group of shapes, but it seems to require another solution with groups. Any suggestions?

I actually found help on shapes, and tried to make it work with groups. Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PFH55/12/ . I get a console error: kinetic is not defined, whereas it's defined.

another edit: I need the solution to work on draggable clones of groups in KineticJS. (What I mean here is that there's an original group in one layer, dragging it creates a clone, which can be dropped only in the second layer, on drop: do the magic of collision detection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to call the method `stopDrag()` which is available for every [Node object](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Node.html).
So once you found collision detection, call this method on the node that is being dragged.

Does this help you?

**Update**

I worked out working example for collision detection with squares. It can be a bit buggy when colliding with 2 objects in certain conditions, so you could improve on this. The current algorithm also assumes all objects are squares.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PFH55/19/

The doObjectsCollide function new returns an array of all objects it collided with. This is then used in the dragBoundCarre. The code belonging to the line `if(collided.length > 1)` can be improved to make the collision detection with two or more objects a little bit better.

Comment: YES !! I didn't know about that method, thank you! But now, after I call stopDrag(), when I want to drag it again the behavior becomes "heavy" :/ chek this fiddle please http://jsfiddle.net/PFH55/4/

Comment: This is because when you call stopDrag(), the two object are overlapping a few pixels (this happens especially on quick mouse movements), so when you start to drag again there is immediate collision and the stopDrag() will be called again. To solve this you should set the x and y coordinate of the dragged object such that it does not overlap the other object. You need to use some geometry maths for that :-) Let me know if you need any help with that.

Comment: Well its not working perfectly (especially again on quick mouse movements and mainly because you loose focus once colliding), but you could put the colliding object back to it's previous position. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PFH55/6/. I guess there is plenty of room to optimize this, but it's a start.

Comment: That's perfect man, at least it's working great! thanks again

Comment: I got something else in mind: when shape1 is dragged and collides with shape2, is it possible to make the shape1 be dragged vertically or horizontally, depending on its position to shape2?

Comment: Looks like you need something like this then: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-shapes-horizontally-or-vertically-tutorial/

Comment: Hi again :) I tried to adapt it with Kinetic.Group (because in my original project I'm dealing with groups of rectangles actually, not images), and I did it. It's only that the first image doesn't move http://jsfiddle.net/PFH55/8/

Comment: Mmm, more things seem broken in that fiddle. Collision detection only seems to work on the first one (thats why the first one doesn't move, it is colliding with itself). I actually think it's not the best idea to use stopDrag(), I think there are better solution. I'll have a look at it tonight. Funnily enough, I'm working on collision on my own (thesis) project right now :-)

Comment: Oh very good :) I'm happy to hear that, good luck with your thesis. I'm working on my graduation project and this issue seems to block me for now...

Comment: Mmm, sorry man, I've been busy with my own thing. I'm wondering what kind of behaviour you want. In my own implementation once object the dragged object intersect, it doesn't stop dragging, but actually moves around the object it collided with (like in your case, fixed horizontal or vertical axis). It feels a lot smoother then my earlier suggestion of putting it to the previous position. Do you want me to make a fiddle with your squares and that same functionality? I can make that in the weekend, if you like...

Comment: Hi @Sijep , yes sure that's exactly the behaviour I want: moving around the object when detecting collision (though I did not know how to explain it better) I'll appreciate if you make a fiddle for me, that's very kind of you :-)

Comment: Thank you again for your time. I tried to make it adapt to Kinetic.Group rather than shapes, because that's the type that I'm working on, but I couldn't (until now)

Comment: Have you maybe got some image or work that you can clarify a bit better what you exactly want? Or if I understand correctly, two rectangle can be moved at the same time (in a group) and you want to add collision detection to that?

Comment: I just want each rectangle to be contained inside a group, and then detect the collision between groups (in the same way), because I'll have to add image to these rectangles.

Comment: Updates to working with group. You could see the rectangle as the background of the group (same width and height as group, so same collision boundary). Then you can add as many green circles, or any Kinetic Shape you like to the group. http://jsfiddle.net/PFH55/22/

Comment: Hi @Sijep , well .. I failed again, this time, at making this possible with cloned groups :( here's what I've done so far: just copied and pasted some of your code http://jsfiddle.net/v778S/10/

Comment: These comments are piling up :S. Anyway, you forgot some important properties (see also comments in code) http://jsfiddle.net/v778S/11/ . Also the right layer wasn't doing anything in your code. Probably it would have been easiest to keep all on one layer and two different groups. Anyway, it took me a while, but learnt  some new stuff myself :-) It's actually quite similar to what I'm making right now myselft

Comment: I'm really happy that you learned something new. Sorry for the comments, I was in a big trouble (+ under time pressure) and it's like you were my only savior, that's why :-P I can't thank you enough for this precious help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50735/discussion-between-sjiep-and-elsa)